# How can I describe a JavaScript class static factory method in TypeScript typings with default export?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, .d.ts

I'm developing a vanilla JavaScript library and have a JS class defined like this:

```js
class MyClass {
  static create() {
    return new MyClass();
  }

  doOneThing() {
    // ...
    return this; 
  }

  doOtherThing() {
    // ...
    return this; 
  }
}

module.exports = MyClass;
```

So I can use dsl-like syntax:

```js
MyClass
  .create()
  .doOneThing()
  .doOtherThing();
```

And I'm trying to add `d.ts` typings file for this class for fellow TypeScript developers could use it too.
Best I've been able to get so far:

```js
export interface MyClassInstance {
    doOneThing(): MyClassInstance;
    doOtherThing(): MyClassInstance;
}

export interface MyClassStatic {
    create(): MyClassInstance;
}

declare const MyClass: MyClassStatic;
export default MyClass;
```

So it works for TypeScript:

```js
import MyClass from "./src/MyClass";
```

But in a JavaScript file my IDE offers me this via autocomplete tool:

```js
MyClass.default.create();
```

I've figured I could add mandatory destructuring, exporting my class wrapped in an object:

```
module.exports = {MyClass};
```

Then both TS and JS work the same way. But I rather won't.

**So I wonder, if there is another way to do that - to have both static method and default export worlkng both in JS and TS**

---

**UPDATE 1**

It appears I can declare a class instead of an interface in my `.d.ts` file like this:

```
declare class MyClass {
    static create(): MyClass;
    doOneThing(): this;
    doOtherThing(): this;
}
export default MyClass;
```

Both JS and TS seems to work fine with it, but I'm still checking out if it's OK or kinda "don't" or bad practice.

---

**UPDATE 2**

Well, it seems it's the best I can get.
I also checked [DefinitelyTyped repo](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) and some modules use `class` declaration in their typings, so I guess it's OK.

Comment: in your tsconfig.json, what module type are you using? `module.exports` is specific to a particular module type...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't have one :) Point is, I'm writing a vanilla JS library, but I wanna add typings for fellow TS developers.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#readme there are plenty of examples on how to type JS modules. That's the whole point of this repo.

Comment: @Keeleon thanks! I'll check it out.

Comment: Is your question about a "*class static factory method*" or about the export? The title and body of the post don't match.

Comment: @Bergi kinda both, I need to describe a static factory method and I want to be able to export it without destructuring. I'm gonna try to adjust the title, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the section [export = and import = require()](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html):

```
// change to
export = MyClass;
```

If is not for the exercise in itself, you could write in TS and pass --declaration to the compiler and let it generate the .d.ts file

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll give it a try

Comment: I checked out `export = MyClass` approach, it appears TS developers will be forced to use special `import MyClass = require("./MyClass");` import, which doesn't seem very nice (please correct me if I'm wrong on that).

Comment: I also used the compiler and it gave me [this](https://gist.github.com/treble-snake/20af2fa2510412d10119e0d10b9ac50c) - added a gist since I can't add code block in comments.

Is it OK to have `class` instead of `interface` in a `.d.ts` file?

Comment: I would really appreciate an opinion on that `class/interface` matter :)